# There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/kestrel/SystemService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have downloaded schema files from a service provider to test their API. I referenced the service in my ASP.NET application and wrote a simple method to send a ping request. I receive following error:

```
Error making ping request: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8080/kestrel/SystemService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Does that mean I need to host the files too? If yes, how?

EDIT:

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ExternalCacheAccessBinding" />
            <binding name="SystemPingBinding" />
            <binding name="SystemInfoBinding" />
            <binding name="SystemTimeBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ExternalCacheAccessBinding"
            contract="WSDLService.ExternalCacheAccessPortType" name="ExternalCacheAccessPort" />
        <endpoint address="https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SystemPingBinding"
            contract="WSDLService.SystemPingPortType" name="SystemPingPort" />
        <endpoint address="https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SystemInfoBinding"
            contract="WSDLService.SystemInfoPortType" name="SystemInfoPort" />
        <endpoint address="https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SystemTimeBinding"
            contract="WSDLService.SystemTimePortType" name="SystemtimePort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the request I am sending:

```
// PING REQUEST
    //

    String payload= "this my payload; there are many like it but this one is mine";
    String someTraceId = "doesntmatter-8176";

    //set up the request parameters into a PingReq object
    PingReq req = new PingReq();
    PingRsp rsp = new PingRsp();
    req.Payload=payload;
    req.TraceId=someTraceId;
    SystemPingPortTypeClient port = new SystemPingPortTypeClient();
    try {
        //run the ping request
        UserNamePasswordClientCredential creds = port.ClientCredentials.UserName;
        creds.UserName = "MyUserName";
        creds.Password = "MyPassword";

        rsp = port.service(req);
        //print results.. payload and trace ID are echoed back in response
        Label1.Text = rsp.Payload;
        Label2.Text = rsp.TraceId;
        Label3.Text = rsp.TransactionId;
        } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    //usually only the error message is useful, not the full stack
    //trace, since the stack trace in is your address space...
    Label1.Text = "Error making ping request: " + ex.Message;
```

Comment: It means that their wsdl points to localhost, you must simply configure endpoint to point to their web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to yourself (localhost). You need to get the public service address that they supply to publicly access the service.

I.e.:

```
http://some.public.domain:8080/kestrel/SystemService
```

You should be able to hit the Service Reference in the browser by just navigating to the service url, and see the service methods. In this case, as in you web.config > https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService .

When I navigate to this URL, I get a "500" fault code. I'd start communicating with them about what you are receiving when just navigating to the URL in your browser.

Comment: I have this address: https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/SystemService
But if I try to point to this one it says something like No endpoint listening at this location